# Change name "Ethereum", "ETH" etc. of a private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm trying to run a private chain with geth and all works properly, but how can I change the name of "Ethereum" and "ETH" and choose a new name and a new TAG?

Thank you.

Comment: The obvious solution is to search in the source code and replace every occurrence. I do not think that geth has a mechanism to do that automatically.